# Mod Rewrite 2 Part Question

Tags: mod-rewrite

I was wondering how can I rewrite the following URL below using mod_rewrite? And is there a online tutorial that explains mod_rewrite for dummies?

How can I rewrite this URL.

```
http://www.example.com/sitemap.php
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4457835/52721. @sleep - you just asked this question. Keep working on that one, we don't do bumps here.

Comment: @Robert: I voted to close, but this post has got a bit of attention since then, so I flagged it for mod review, with the recommendation that the two questions be merged.

Comment: Fair enough. Merger is really the way to go, I think.

Comment: I think you want to rewrite sitemap.xml to sitemap.php, not the other way around, don't you? You want requests for sitemap.xml to be handled by sitemap.php, which is the opposite of what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule sitemap.php sitemap.xml
```

That should do it.

Comment: Worked when I tested it... You might need to add `RewriteEngine On` above it, if you're putting this into an .htaccess file.

Comment: its on but its still not working its not displaying the xml data at all.

Comment: Is there a RewriteCond line above it that doesn't have a matching RewriteRule, or are there other RewriteRules there as well? You might have to put this one first (and add " [L]" to the end to make mod_rewrite stop after changing it).

Comment: I don't think it should have any effect (it didn't on my test box), but the "www.^example.com" in the rule there should be "www.example.com" without the ^.

Comment: that was a type o, but I still cant get it the `RewriteRule sitemap.php sitemap.xml` work.

Comment: Your webserver IS reading the .htaccess file, right? Try adding some garbage in there to see if it throws an error. If it doesn't, it's not reading the .htaccess.

Comment: my hosting is reading the .htaccess file I'm using godaddy if that helps.

Comment: Try adding `Options -Multiviews` above your rewrite rules... apparently GoDaddy's mod_rewrite support can be a little odd.

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas, unfortunately... about the only other thing I can see on the web is that Godaddy is a little slow when the .htaccess file is new, and that it can take anywhere from 2-24 hours to take effect (though once it's in place, edits take effect within 3 minutes, which still seems like a long time to me). Wish I could help more... sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options for this, depending on how you want it to work.

The simplest way to redirect one file to another is to simply use the `Redirect` directive:

```
 Redirect /sitemap.php http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

This will do a 302 redirect by default, but you can change it to a 301 by adding the status code as a first parameter, i.e.:

```
 Redirect 301 /sitemap.php http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

In both cases, this will result in a round trip back to the browser, so the address bar will change to show the new `sitemap.xml` filename. If you don't want that, you can use the `RewriteRule` directive:

```
 RewriteRule ^sitemap.php$ /sitemap.xml [L]
```

Note that this is how you would write the rule from what is called a "per-dir context" which just means that the rule is being written from within either a `.htaccess` file, or from a `<Directory>` block. If you're writing it from your main config, then you would need a leading slash (i.e. `^/sitemap.php$`) to show that you mean for the rule to match from the document root.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
RewriteRule ^/sitemap.php$ /sitemap.xml
```

As for a tutorial, have you tried the official [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_intro.html)?
Following that, there are lots of useful examples in the [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) and [Advanced URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html)... they might be complex but it does have examples of many common rewrite tasks.

Comment: the RewriteRule did not work:( thanks for the tutorials though