# Mod_Rewrite file extension

Tags: xml, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mod Rewrite 2 Part Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457835/mod-rewrite-2-part-question)

How can I rewrite the file extension .php to .xml for this just file.

```
http://www.example.com/sitemap.php
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Current mod

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.^example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```